# Add ToolTip to StripMenuItem C#

Tags: c#, tooltip, menustrip

So I have a UserControl Form. Where  I have a MenuStrip

[image]

So I want to add a ToolTip on my MenuStripItems ( which are only pictures ). But setting the text on `ToolTipText` did not help at all. Also tried

```
 adaugaToolStripMenuItem.ToolTipText = "Click for the current time";
            adaugaToolStripMenuItem.AutoToolTip = false;
```

So I have no idea, any help? Is there a way I can add a ToolTip or some kind of hint to my MenuStripItems ?

Comment: have you tried a google search..? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/75834/how-to-attach-tooltip-with-menustrip

Comment: Already said I tried with ToolTipText property from the object. Did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure `ShowItemToolTips` of the `MenuStrip` container is also set to `true`? It's `false` by default. You may want to use its other property `DefaultShowItemToolTips` instead.

[MSDN Link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.showitemtooltips%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also check the item's `AutoToolTip` property is set to `false`. Its default value is `true`, and that means it uses the `Text` property as tooltip.

[MSDN Link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.autotooltip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you ShowItemToolTips was the problem! Thank you very much!